# How to get data from array is struct

Tags: ios, swift

I had write struct looks like this:

```
struct MSProduct: Codable {
    let categories : [Categories]?
    let tags : [Tags]?
    let images : [Images]?
    let attributes : [Attributes]?
    let default_attributes : [String]?
    let variations : [String]?
    let grouped_products : [String]?
    let menu_order : Int?
    let meta_data : [MetaData]?
    let _links : Links?
}

struct Attributes : Codable {
    let id: Int?
    let name: String?
    let position: Int?
    let visible: Bool?
    let variation: Bool?
    let options: [String]?
}
```

And I want to get data from let attributes which is in struct MSProduct but this reference to other struct Attributes. Can someone tell me how can I get this data to show in tableview?

Comment: It's not clear what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

after parsing the json suppose you have stored it in `product` variable then,

```
// attributes array
let productAttributes : [Attributes]? = product.attributes

//you can use it normally like
let name = productAttributes[0].name ?? "" //default value since name is optional

//inside table row 
let name = productAttributes[indexPath.row].name ?? "" //default value since name is optional
```

use `productAttributes` array to populate the tableView